# DirectoryInfo.Exists cannot find my mapped network drive C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

```
protected void btnAutomaticUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\space-bar\UZ\UZ Dept\Management\Data\directory_exists_here\");
    bool atLeastOneSuccessfulUpload = false;
    bool possibleFormatChange = false;

    lblMessages.Text = string.Empty;
    lblResults.Text = "<span style='font-size:large; font-weight:bold'><u>Results Log</u></span><br><br>";

    //If our destination directory does not exist, exit
    if (!dir.Exists)
    {
        lblResults.Text += "<span style='color:Red'>Expected directory does not exist!</span><br>" + dir.FullName;
        return;
    }
```

So I have been trying to run this code on a live server with a mapped network drive but it always seems to not be able to find the folder. Although when I am running this on Debug or LocalHost mode, it seems to be able to find the directory with no problem. Any idea as to why it's not working even with a UNC path coded? Does it have anything to do with permissions if any?

I am trying to build an automatic file upload parser.

Comment: Is the code running as the same user on both the server and locally while debugging?  If they are different users, it could be a permission problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running under IIS it almost certainly doesn't have the rights to access a network resource. Check the Application Pool identity in IIS to determine which user your application is running under - its likely be a very restricted system account. This can be changed by altering the Application Pool settings in IIS Manager.

Comment: This seems to be the answer. Sucks because I don't have access to IIS Manager yet.